# Can we write an aggregate Query inside a Mongodb Function?

Tags: mongodb

I am working with mongo shell.I tried creating function in mongodb but i am unable to find example in which i can write aggregate queries inside a function.

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "myFunction",
    value: function (x) {
        return  db.table2.find().pretty();
    }
});
```

db.eval("myFunction('test')")

I want the collection data but its returning me an object :

```
{
       "_mongo" : {
               "slaveOk" : false,
               "host" : "EMBEDDED",
               "_defaultSession" : [Object]
       },
       "_db" : {
               "_mongo" : {
                       "slaveOk" : false,
                       "host" : "EMBEDDED",
                       "_defaultSession" : [Object]
               },
               "_name" : "dashboard_db",
               "_session" : [Object]
       },
       "_collection" : {
               "_mongo" : {
                       "slaveOk" : false,
                       "host" : "EMBEDDED",
                       "_defaultSession" : [Object]
               },
               "_db" : {
                       "_mongo" : {
                               "slaveOk" : false,
                               "host" : "EMBEDDED",
                               "_defaultSession" : [Obj
                       },
                       "_name" : "dashboard_db",
                       "_session" : [Object]
               },
               "_shortName" : "table2",
               "_fullName" : "dashboard_db.table2"
       },
       "_ns" : "dashboard_db.table2",
       "_query" : {

       },
       "_fields" : null,
       "_limit" : 0,
       "_skip" : 0,
       "_batchSize" : 0,
       "_options" : 0,
       "_cursor" : null,
       "_numReturned" : 0,
       "_special" : false,
       "_prettyShell" : true

}
```

How can i get collection data from a function?

Comment: [`eval()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) is deprecated and actually approaching complete removal. Whatever reason you "think" you need "server-side JavaScript evaluation" for is most often far better handled natively in the coding enviroment of choice. You also should read into that the future direction of "server-side JavaScript" execution eventually being removed in ALL forms. It was only ever a "band aid" solution anyway until native operators were added. They are "mostly" added now.

Comment: As for the "error", you want `toArray()` here and NOT `pretty()`, since what is actually being returned is a "cursor" and `pretty()` does not do what you think it does in this context. But really, don't do it.

Comment: thanks for the information.. :) Neil Lunn